# How to Setup a Sign up and login form in android studio and link it with SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I have some problem when I get to link the two form in my android application with SQLite database can you please help me to get the right code because, I try many time to find where the e problem and I didn't get it.
this is the code in loginActivity linked with form of login, I think the code is all correct but I have a problem is the user when he try to insert the email and password that he signup with it it show that it's invalid data in spite of the data is correct, I think the problem is with the the section of the if statement (res.getCount()== 1).

```
 package com.example.cs50;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class loginActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView dont_have_account;
    EditText email,password;
    Button signin;
    DBapp my_DB;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login2);

        email=findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
        password=findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
        signin=findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);

        my_DB = new DBapp(this);

        signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                attemp_login();
            }
        });

        //make listener for text dont have account
        dont_have_account=findViewById(R.id.textview_dont_have_account);
        dont_have_account.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(loginActivity2.this,signupActivity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void attemp_login() {
        String Email=email.getText().toString();
        String pass=password.getText().toString();

        if(!isEmailValid(Email)){
            Toast.makeText( this, "Email Invalid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(!isPasswordValid(pass)){
            Toast.makeText(  this, "Password Invalid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Cursor res = my_DB.login_user(Email,pass);
        if (res.getCount()== 1){
            final Intent intent = new Intent(loginActivity2.this,Home.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(  this, "Invalid Account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    private boolean isEmailValid(String email){
        return email.contains("@");
    }

    private boolean isPasswordValid(String password){
        return password.length()>6;
    }


}
```

the class of Signup Activity it totally work for me but ,I must have another statement to check that if the data already have insert in the signup form (account already signup), and after that it must to redirect him to the login form, but I didn't know how to implement this statement, can you please help me to setup the correct statement to do that this is the code of The signup Activity.

```
package com.example.cs50;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import cn.pedant.SweetAlert.SweetAlertDialog ;

public class signupActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView already_signin;
    EditText username,email,password;
    Button signup;
    DBapp my_DB;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup2);

        username=findViewById(R.id.editName);
        email = findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
        password=findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
        signup=findViewById(R.id.buttonSignup);
        my_DB = new DBapp(this);

        Register_user();

        //make listener for text already sign in
        already_signin =findViewById(R.id.textView_alreadysign);
        already_signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(signupActivity2.this,loginActivity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void Register_user() {

        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                String Email=email.getText().toString();
                String pass=password.getText().toString();
                String user=username.getText().toString();

                 if(!isEmailValid(Email)){
                    Toast.makeText(signupActivity2.this, "Is Not Valid Email try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(!isPasswordvalid(pass)){
                    Toast.makeText( signupActivity2.this, "Too Small password length !!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();
                }
                else if(Email.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(signupActivity2.this, "Mail field Required !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(pass.isEmpty()) {
                     Toast.makeText(signupActivity2.this, "Password Field Required !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
                else {
                     boolean isInserted= my_DB.insertData(Email,pass,user);
                     new SweetAlertDialog( signupActivity2.this, SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE)
                             .setTitleText("Message")
                             .setContentText("You are Registered")
                             .setConfirmText("OK")
                             .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener(){
                                 @Override
                                 public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                                         Intent i =new Intent( signupActivity2.this, loginActivity2.class);
                                         startActivity(i);
                             }
                             })
                     .show();
                 }




            }
        });
    }

    private boolean isEmailValid(String email){
        return email.contains("@");
    }

    private boolean isPasswordvalid(String password){
        return password.length()>6;
    }
}
```

and Finally this is  the code of the database

```
package com.example.cs50;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DBapp extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DB";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "user";
    public static final String COL_2 = "EMAIL";
    public static final String COL_3 = "USERNAME";
    public static final String COL_4 = "PASSWORD";


    public DBapp(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("Create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, EMAIL TEXT , USERNAME TEXT,PASSWORD TEXT )");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }


    //registration

    public boolean insertData(String email, String password, String username) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues ContentValues = new ContentValues();
        ContentValues.put(COL_2, email);
        ContentValues.put(COL_3, username);
        ContentValues.put(COL_4, password);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, ContentValues);
        if (result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }


    //LOGIN

    public Cursor login_user(String email, String password) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery(" Select * from " + TABLE_NAME + " where EMAIL= '" + email + " 'and PASSWORD= '" + password + "'", null);
        return res;
    }
}
```

**if you didn't understand something in the code please mention that for me to explain more the code for you.**

Comment: thank you so much for this informations i have changed what you say in my code and it's work for me thak you

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**

I believe that your issue is that you have an errant space in the query that is added to the end of the email.

**Fix**

Change :-

```
Cursor res = db.rawQuery(" Select * from " + TABLE_NAME + " where EMAIL= '" + email + " 'and PASSWORD= '" + password + "'", null);
```

to :-

```
Cursor res = db.rawQuery(" Select * from " + TABLE_NAME + " where EMAIL= '" + email + "' and PASSWORD= '" + password + "'", null);
```

**Recommended FIX**

However, it would be considered better practice to use the query convenience method and to utilise parameter binding which offers protection against SQL Injection.

As such you may wish to consider using:-

```
public Cursor login_user(String email, String password) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,"email=? AND password=?",new String[]{email,password},null,null,null );
}
```

This has the advantage that the values will be suitable enclosed in single quotes and the accidental errant extra space would not result.

**Recommended other changes**

You should also note that when traversing activities, that the correct way is to **`finish()`** the child activity it will then return to the parent activity. Starting the parent activity actually results in the actual parent activity being destroyed and a new parent activity being started.

e.g. consider using :-

```
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                                //Intent i =new Intent( signupActivity2.this, loginActivity2.class);
                                //startActivity(i);
                                finish(); //<<<<<<<<<< RETURN TO PARENT (invoking) ACTIVITY
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
```

- old code commented out.